# Cheese webcam problem

Tags: webcam, logitech, cheese

I have got a new webcam: Logitech. But today when I have connected it to my pc (ubuntu 12.10) and tried to open with `Cheese Webcam Booth` I've got something like this:

---

[image: cheese opens, can take picture, but it shows nothing]

---

Problem is that I can take picture and it takes picture cool, but privew area is black, and it don't shows nothing.
What is my problem??

**p.s.** works good with "Kamerka"

**EDIT** camera is `logitech C910`

Comment: [Someone here says](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=93717&f=47#p537496) that installing Cheese via the software manager didn't work for him, and so, here removed it, and installed it via command-line with this command: `sudo apt-get install cheese` and that seems to have worked for him. Weird, but you can give it a try.

Comment: if possible, please share the model, number and revision of your webcam with us.

Comment: ah sure just a moment, ill do both

Comment: @its_me sorry didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

For me I found Cheesecam to be buggy, I used cheese cam on my Dell I found all the colour to be off almost golden, really annoying.  I'd stick with Kamerka.  In Kamerka picture looked great!  But in Cheese cam under the same light conditions still look like a yellow bulb was in the room and the colour was very dark.  I don't think that it senses the light very good.  I had both programs running side by side and Cheese cam was terrible.

Comment: but what about shooting video ?

Comment: shooting video I had issues also with cheesecam.

Comment: it is sad to make video without watching what it shoots :D, but thanks anyway